# Camel rest route not returning status code on exception

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have created a camel route with the following exception handling:

```
onException(BadRequestException.class)
    .handled(true)
    .process(exchange -> {
        System.out.println("Reached processor");
        System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
    })
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));
```

I make a request to `http://localhost:8080/services/rest/endpoint?key=value`

In a bean, I have some validation that says that two query parameters are required, `key` and `keyTwo`. `keyTwo` isn't present, so I throw a `BadRequestException`:

```
public void assertRequiredParametersPresentOnExchange() throws BadRequestException {
    try {
        requiredParameters.stream()
            .forEach(p -> assertNotNull(p));
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        throw new BadRequestException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

When I execute the URL, I can see `Reached processor` output from the exception handler above, but then nothing happens. Postman waits for a reply for ~60 seconds and then gives me status code 23.

What am I missing here? MEP? Setting some property on the exchange?

Comment: I'm usually handling the HTTP error response in an [own bean](https://github.com/RovoMe/camel-rest-dsl-with-spring-security/blob/master/src/main/java/at/rovo/awsxray/routes/beans/PrepareErrorResponse.java#L34) which is invoked by [exception handlers](https://github.com/RovoMe/camel-rest-dsl-with-spring-security/blob/master/src/main/java/at/rovo/awsxray/routes/api/BaseAPIRouteBuilder.java#L33) where I set `msg.setFault(false)` explicitely as Camel or maybe Jetty would otherwise overwrite my defined status code with a 500 one. Not sure which server implementation you are using though

Comment: Thank you, I took this into consideration when changing the status code. The processor was mostly placed there to track down where the problem occurred. It is now handled and formatted to a generic json error body, similar to your link!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you are getting the enums ordinal which is 23. Could you try to replace the the enum

```
org.apache.http.HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST
```

instead of

```
org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
```

and see if it makes any difference

Comment: assuming u are using org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST in your example